# Java Priority queue error about poll

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am having trouble with priority queue of poll. My try is this:

```
public int [][] MST(int i, int prim[][], int mst[][], int vertices, int counter, PriorityQueue priorityQueue){
    Table table = new Table();
    int next_row;
    for(int j=0;j<vertices;j++)
    {
        table.s = i;
        table.d = j;
        table.w = prim[i][j];

        priorityQueue.add(table);
    }
    table = priorityQueue.poll();
    mst[counter][0] = table.s;
    mst[counter][1] = table.d;
    return mst;

}
```

Then I got error at priorityQueue.poll(). It says required Table, but found java.lang.Object.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: With a typecast, or via Generics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Typecasting as

```
PriorityQueue prq = new PriorityQueue(); 
prq.add (new Table (values)) ; 
Table data = (Table) prq.poll();
```

Answer (score 0):

you may specify the type of items in the declaration of the priorityQueue

```
PriorityQueue < Integer >  prq = new PriorityQueue < Integer > (); 
prq.add (new Integer (5)) ; 
Integer number = prq.poll();
```

but if you can't change the declaration you could use typeCasting

```
PriorityQueue prq = new PriorityQueue(); 
prq.add (new Integer (5)) ; 
Integer number = (Integer) prq.poll();
```

Comment: His element class is `Table`, not `Integer`.

Comment: I'm just giving an example